# WPF Code Behind: DataGridTextColumn shows Column headers but not data from xmlprovider with xpath

Tags: c#, wpf, xpath, code-behind

I'm trying to show data from XMLProvider with XPath. Because of the the dynamic nature of the xml file I need to load the data via code behind.

I'm looking for a datagrid looking like this:

```
Sensor    BIS  MAN  BIS  MAN
-----------------------------
Sensor1   45   43   44   46
Sensor2   45   43   43   45
```

*FYI: above the grid I'll be showing a fake super header to group BIS & MAN values (in case you don't understand why BIS & MAN keywords are repeating)*

XAML code for the datagrid:

```
<DataGrid Name="MDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False"></DataGrid>
```

This is the XML file sample data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ShipData>
  <Draught>
    <Measures>
      <Mdata>M1</Mdata>
      <Mdata>M2</Mdata>
    </Measures>
    <Sensor Name="Sensor1">
      <Measurement>
        <Bis>45</Bis>
        <Man>43</Man>
      </Measurement>
      <Measurement>
        <Bis>44</Bis>
        <Man>46</Man>
      </Measurement>
    </Sensor>
    <Sensor Name="Sensor2">
      <Measurement>
        <Bis>45</Bis>
        <Man>43</Man>
      </Measurement>
      <Measurement>
        <Bis>43</Bis>
        <Man>45</Man>
      </Measurement>
    </Sensor>
  </Draught>
</ShipData>
```

And here is the code behind c# code I'm using:

```
// loading xml for grid
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(_file_location_); // (it does find the xml)

// setting the xml provider
XmlDataProvider _xmlDataProvider = new XmlDataProvider();
_xmlDataProvider.Document = doc;
_xmlDataProvider.XPath = @"/ShipData/Draught/Sensor";

// Setting the datacontext for 
MDataGrid.DataContext = _xmlDataProvider; 

// Creating the column Sensor (as an example) and create a new binding for xpath
var dataGridTextColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();

Binding bindingSensor = new Binding();
bindingSensor.Source = _xmlDataProvider;
bindingSensor.XPath = "@Name";
dataGridTextColumn.Binding = bindingSensor;

dataGridTextColumn.Header = "Sensor";

// other repeating columns (bis+man ...) omitted for this example

// adding the column to the datagrid
MDataGrid.Columns.Add(dataGridTextColumn);
```

The header for the sensor column is showing, but there's no data listed in the grid. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you need an extra Binding as someone else pointed me out. I don't know why exactly, but it does the job perfectly.

```
// loading xml for grid
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(_file_location_); // (it does find the xml)

// setting the xml provider
XmlDataProvider _xmlDataProvider = new XmlDataProvider();
_xmlDataProvider.Document = doc;
_xmlDataProvider.XPath = @"/ShipData/Draught/Sensor";

// Setting the datacontext (updated code)
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Source = _xmlDataProvider;
MDataGrid.SetBinding(DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);

// Creating the column Sensor (as an example) and create a new binding for xpath
var dataGridTextColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();

Binding bindingSensor = new Binding();
bindingSensor.XPath = "@Name";
dataGridTextColumn.Binding = bindingSensor;

dataGridTextColumn.Header = "Sensor";

// other repeating columns (bis+man ...) omitted for this example

// adding the column to the datagrid
MDataGrid.Columns.Add(dataGridTextColumn);
```

It does also work for the added columns I wanted (using dynamically adjusted XPath code)

Credit goes to: **Magnus (MM8)**

Answer (score 1):

That isn't *extra* as you state in answer. That is indeed required step. DataGrid display data supplied to `ItemsSource` property, so there won't be any data displayed if you didn't set `ItemsSource`. Instead of manually setting `ItemsSource` binding in code, you can do it in XAML :

```
<DataGrid Name="MDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
```

and set `DataContext` from code-behind as you already did :

```
......
// Setting the datacontext for 
MDataGrid.DataContext = _xmlDataProvider; 
......
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer too. I mistakenly thought the xmlProvider would supply all needed details like ItemsSource, but as it seems it doens't.